# Please explain SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER() function

Tags: authentication, users, derby

Can someone please explain to me how `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER()` works? I tried adding a new user like this: `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER('user', 'someP@ss')`, and it gave an exception *Error code 30000, SQL state 4251K: The first credentials created must be those of the DBO.*

I found the function in the Derby Docs, but it showed the Fred example, which I also tried, but it gave me the same exception.

I created the database via NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Read the secderby.pdf, page 41, "Configuring NATIVE authentication":

Use the SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER system procedure to add credentials
for the Database Owner. **Remember that the Database Owner is the user who
created the database.**

I assume you created your DB without username/password or you tried to create a different user then the one when you created the DB.

**Working example:**
`CONNECT 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true;user=admin;password=admin123';
call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER('admin', 'admin123' );`
You see in the above example the DBO (database owner) is 'admin' and for the very first SYSCS_CREATE_USER call, the user must be 'admin' too.

**Not working example:**
`CONNECT 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myBadDB;create=true;';
call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER('admin', 'admin123' );`